# Acessando Painel do usuario através do Admin, Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, html, laravel

Preciso acessar o painel do usuário listado pelo painel administrativo em Laravel.
Estou copiando de um outro projeto que está 100%. Porem no meu não funciona.

meu html:

```html
                      @foreach ($users as $row)
                      <tr>
                        <td> {{ $row->id }}</td>
                        <td> {{ $row->name }}</td>
                        <td> {{ $row->username }}</td>
                        <td> {{ $row->email }}</td>

                        @inject('usuarios', 'App\User')
                       
                        <td> {{$row->getPacote()->nome}}</td>
                        <td> 
                          <a href="/role-edit/{{ $row->id }}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
                        
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <select class="form-control operacaoUsuario" data-id="{{$row->id}}" data-username="{{$row->username}}">
                                        <option >Selecione uma ação</option>
                                        <option  value="acessar_usuario">Acessar painel</option>
                                       </select>
                                    </div>
                                  </td>
```

meu script:

```js
<script>
function acessarPainel(user_id) {
    if (!confirm('Ao acessar um novo painel, a sessão atual será cancelada.Continuar com a ação?')) {
        return false;
    } else {
        location.href = "<?= url('/' . $uriPainel . '/acessar/') ?>/" + user_id;
    }
}

$(".operacaoUsuario").change(function () {
    element = $(this);
    user_id = element.attr('data-id');
    username = element.attr('data-username');
    val = element.val();
    if (val == 'editar_usuario') {
        editarUsuario(user_id);
    } else if (val == 'ativar_usuario') {
        ativarUsr(user_id);
    } else if (val == 'acessar_usuario') {
        acessarPainel(user_id);
    } else if (val == 'ativar_saque' || val == 'desativar_saque') {
        mudarCol(user_id, 'saque');
    } else if (val == 'confirmar_proposta') {
        if (confirm("ATENÇÃO,ANTES DE CONFIRMAR VERIFIQUE SE O PACOTE ATUAL DO USUÁRIO É O MESMO ESCOLHIDO NO PAGAMENTO DA PROPOSTA.Clique em cancelar para verificar as informações ou em OK para confirmar a proposta.")) {
            mudarCol(user_id, 'status_proposta');
        } else {
            editarUsuario(user_id);

        }
    } else if (val == 'confirmar_preparatorio') {
        mudarCol(user_id, 'status_preparatorio');
    } else if (val == 'cadastrar_afiliado') {
        location.href = "<?= url('cadastro/') ?>/" + username;
    } else if (val == 'ver_extratos') {
        location.href = "<?= url('/painel/transacoes/') ?>?user_id=" + user_id;
    } else if (val == 'ver_etiquetas') {
        location.href = "<?= url('/' . $uriPainel . '/etiquetas/') ?>?user_id=" + user_id;
    } else if (val == 'registro_atividade') {
        location.href = "<?= url('/' . $uriPainel . '/registroAtividade/') ?>/" + user_id;
    } else if (val == 'pagar_binario') {
        if (confirm("Está operação não pode ser cancelada.Você tem certeza?")) {
            location.href = "<?= url('/' . $uriPainel . '/pagarBinarioNovamente/') ?>/" + user_id;
        }
    } else if (val == 'pagar_indicacao') {
        if (confirm("Está operação não pode ser cancelada.Você tem certeza?")) {
            location.href = "<?= url('/' . $uriPainel . '/pagarIndicacao/') ?>/" + user_id;
        }
    }


});
</script>
```

meu web:

```js
  Route::get('acessar/{id}', 'UserController@acessar');
  Route::get('usuarios', 'UserController@manage_usr');
```

controller:

```html
        public function acessar($id) {

        if (\Auth::loginUsingId($id)) {
            return redirect('/');
        } else {
            return redirect('/admin/usuarios')
                            ->withErrors(['Usuário não encontrado.']);
        }
    }
```

E ao clicar tenho a seguinte imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Código do controller?

Comment: public function acessar($id) {

        if (\Auth::loginUsingId($id)) {
            return redirect('/');
        } else {
            return redirect('/admin/usuarios')
                            ->withErrors(['Usuário não encontrado.']);
        }
    }

Comment: resolvido, alterei o if e deu tudo certo

location.href = "<?= url('/acessar/') ?>/" + user_id;